# Templating in Python

Tags: python, templates

Hey guys i'm currently working on a project containing details of passengers for a airline ticket in a dataset. I need to run a **python script** which prints out the airline tickets **pdf** using **templating** in python. It has to be a template similar to any airline tickets.

---

I'm a beginner in python. So it would be helpful if i could get any reference for my work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReportLab](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) it is very extensive.

First, download an install **ReportLab**

Then try this on Python command line:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm
c = canvas.Canvas('ex.pdf')
c.drawImage('ar.jpg', 0, 0, 10*cm, 10*cm)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

ReportLab is the best for PDF generation
However, it's also a bit more complicated

Try [Link 1](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/) [Link 2](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/21/reportlab-tables-creating-tables-in-pdfs-with-python/) For better understand

Comment: Thanks mate!! Appreciate it.